# How to use blackcoffee with grunt watch

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, blackcoffee

I was hoping that [grunt-contrib-coffee](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) could work with [blackcoffee](https://www.npmjs.org/package/blackcoffee) but it seems that it uses the coffee-script npm module directly instead of calling the `coffee` executable which would have invoked blackcoffee. I have looked around to see if there are any pre-existing Grunt plugins for blackcoffee but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Any recommendations as to how to go about configuring Grunt so that `grunt watch` will let me compile my blackcoffee code?

Answer (score 0):

don't know if that works, but i think it should:

1. fork grunt-contrib-coffee
2. rename it in your package.json to `grunt-blackcoffee`
3. replace coffee-script dependency, and replace with blackcoffee in your package.json
4. search for the coffee-script require in the grunt task, [currently it's here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee/blob/master/tasks/coffee.js#L181):

   ```
   return require('coffee-script').compile(code, coffeeOptions);
   ```

   and replace it with

   ```
   return require('blackcoffee').compile(code, coffeeOptions);
   ```
5. publish it to npm

if you don't want to publish to npm, you can install packages from git:

```
$ npm install git+ssh://your-git-repo.git --save
```